# Using Google Play Services location functionality with Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.android, google-play-services

I followed the steps mention under section "Location Client" on  https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/maps_and_location/location/

There in the example it implements `IGooglePlayServicesClientConnectionCallbacks, IGooglePlayServicesClientOnConnectionFailedListener`interfaces in the activity class.

From where this interface coming from? i can't resolve them in my code. What nuget package should I add and what should I import ?

Answer (score 0):

> From where this interface coming from? i can't resolve them in my code. What nuget package should I add and what should I import ?

You need download the `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base` package :

[image]

And you need  [Check for Google Play Services](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/remote-notifications-with-gcm/) when you use these api :

```
public bool IsPlayServicesAvailable()
{
    int resultCode = GoogleApiAvailability.Instance.IsGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.Success)
    {
        if (GoogleApiAvailability.Instance.IsUserResolvableError(resultCode))
            msgText.Text = GoogleApiAvailability.Instance.GetErrorString(resultCode);
        else
        {
            msgText.Text = "Sorry, this device is not supported";
            Finish();
        }
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        msgText.Text = "Google Play Services is available.";
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: My project already have the playservices.base nuget package but VS not suggesting me to import IGooglePlayServicesClientConnectionCallbacks. Also I searched on the github repo for playservices.base https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents there also I can't find content for IGooglePlayServicesClientConnectionCallbacks.

Comment: Please use `Android.Gms.Common.Apis.GoogleApiClient.IConnectionCallbacks` try again.